# C# Excel Interop Error: The file is being used by another process

Tags: c#, excel

In my project, mt aim is to edit and move a file. I have removed all the editing sections for simplicity, as they do not seem to be causing the error. I have tested the error with just this code and it still occurs.

This is my code:

```
Application xlApp = new Application();
Workbooks xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
Workbook xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(Path.GetFullPath(fileNameWithPath));
Sheets xlWorksheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets;
Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorksheets.get_Item(1);
Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

string fileNameWithExtension = GetFileNameWithExtension(fileNameWithPath);

xlWorkbook.Close(false);
xlApp.Quit();
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlRange);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheets);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbooks);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
xlRange = null;
xlWorksheet = null;
xlWorksheets = null;
xlWorkbook = null;
xlWorkbooks = null;
xlApp = null;
GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

File.Move(fileNameWithPath, myNewPath);
```

When running this I am getting an error message when the application tries to move the file: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

I am pretty sure I have closed off all of the COM objects and have done all the recommendations I could find online to get this to work. Any ideas as to what I have missed?

Comment: I can't replicate your issue with just that code. Opens, closes and then moves the file without issue. (Win 8 / Excel 2013)

Comment: try killing any processes of excel or do a reboot

Comment: @Equalsk It seems I had some excel things running which I could see when I went to Task Manage --> Details. I restarted the PC and it works now. Thanks for trying to replicate; that helped me get it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sysinterals to check, which process cause this issue. In general i would proof before doing those things, if you have write access for the file.

Method for proofing write access:

```
public static bool FileHasWriteAccess(string Path)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.File.Open(Path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite).Dispose();
        return true;
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Take a look at: [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't actually proof it. You could conceivably have a situation where `FileHasWriteAccess` returns `true`, then another process takes a lock, then you try to write to it.

Comment: Thats true, but if you lock the file just one line before using it, the chance is really low. You can even retry in a simple loop with a given amount of tries...

Comment: It's rare, but it's the type of bug that you get a bug report for, can't reproduce it very well, and have a hard time fixing in general when you've forgotten about this code.